# What exactly is this "variable"/"instantiation" in the example code i made?

Tags: c#, class, variables, instantiation

So I have some doubts about the class and its variables, mostly about the "Message message;" in the code I just wrote before.

My main question is: **Why I can declare this `Message message;` in the class scope and I don't need to put it in a method scope?** Because I ***THINK*** an instantiation needs to be put in a method, furthermore, what exactly is this `Message message;` Is it an variable? Is it an instantiation?

```
public class Message
{
    public string MessageValue() => "Hello World";
}
public class Write
{
    Message message;
    private void printMessage() => Console.WriteLine(message.messagevalue());
}
```

Comment: `Why i can declare this "Message message;" in the class scope and i don't need to put it in a method scope?` The term for that in C# is a `field`. It is a variable scoped to an instance of the class rather than to the method. I suspect you _meant_ to use `Message message = new Message();` otherwise you will get an exception since `message` is `null` (not instantiated).

Comment: You devlared a field of reference type Message. But you havent created an instance in that field. It has null initial value. Thus your WriteLine will throw NullPointerException.

Comment: You need to make "messagevalue()" to static method to call it like above.you declare a variable that is null and call a method that is not static!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to keep in mind. `Message` in your example is the *type* and `message` is the name of the actual field or variable.

### Variable declarations

```
Message message;
```

You're basically declaring the type of variable, and what the name (which could be something like `Message foo` as well).

### Instantiation

```
new Message();
SomeMethod(new Message());
```

We are creating the new instance of `Message`. We are then using assignment to store that new instance to hold on to it.

In the second example we're passing a new instance of `Message` to this class that is expecting it, even though we aren't saving it to a variable.

### Assignment

```
message1 = message2;
```

Pretty self explanatory.

### All at once

```
Message message = new Message();
```

Here we're doing all of the above. We're creating the variable, saying what type, and then creating a new instance. This is very common. So common, that people got tired of writing out the `Message` three times, so C# added a new syntax that does literally the same thing with no difference:

`var message = new Message();` C# can tell what type `message is supposed to be and will make` message` that type, so we don't have to be redundant.

About instantation needing to be in a method, you're hunch is actually correct.

Doing

```
public class Foo
{
    public Message message = new Message();
}
```

Is perfectly valid C# syntax, will work fine and will compile. However, what it's doing under the hood is actually this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Message message;

    public Foo() 
    {
        message = new Message();
    }
}
```

And this actually caused an issue for me when working in Unity. In Unity, if an object is created that inherits from `MonoBehavior`, you're not allowed to create it using constructors anymore, and it somehow bypasses calling the constructor altogether. Its really annoying and has made things much more complicated.

One of the complications is that those field initializers were never called so I was getting null reference exceptions without realizing how. It took me a while to figure out.

Now I have to put it manually in the `Awake()` method that Unity calls when creating the object, basically what the compiler would have done.

**Edit:** As Thomas Schremser pointed out, `var` only works inside of methods.

And for more clarification, `Message message;` is a field deceleration (variable deceleration if inside a function), where the `Message` is the type, and the `message` is the field/variable. The syntax is `Type memberName = new Type()`

A field is a variable that belongs to a class, either belonging to the class instance or the class itself. For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public class int InstanceField;   // This belongs to individual instances
    public static int StaticField;    // This belongs to the class itself 
                                      // (accessed via Foo.StaticField)
    public var ImplicitlyType = 3;    // ERROR: Fields can't be implicitly typed

    public void Bar()
    {
        int notAField;           // This is only accessible in this function,
                                 // Making it a local variable, not a field
        var implicitlyType = 4;  // This works because implicitlyTyped is a local variable
                                 // It's type is also of int, not var
    }
    public void Baz(int alsoNotAField)
    {
        // alsoNotAField is a parameter. It's value will be given from other methods
        // alsoNotAField is also only usable in the scope of this method
        notAField++; // ERROR: notAField can't be used here, because it's limited to Bar()
        
    }
}
```

A field is a type of variable that belongs to a class, and a method is a type of function that belongs to a class.

Variables outside of functions are called fields, and there's no way to have a function outside of a class in C#. So, in a sense, C# only has methods.

Comment: Good answer. But since the OP talked about fields it’s worth mentioning that `var` doesn’t work with them.

Comment: thank you a lot you let a lot of things clear in here, but one thing that i saw in another comment as well, the "Message message;" is a field then? (which you could access then the different properties and values from the class Message through the variable message)

Comment: Thanks you guys, I updated my answer with the more information.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at write class and drill down into it:

```
public class Write
{
    Message message;
    private void printMessage() => Console.WriteLine(message.messagevalue());
}
```

The  `Message message;` is a field, a field which is scoped to an instance of your class called message.

the definition of **field** from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields):

> A field is a variable of any type that is declared directly in a class
>   or struct. Fields are members of their containing type.

meaning that `message` is a field type of `Message` class and you can use it to access `Message` class through `Write` class.

for example:

```
Write write = new Write();
write.message = new Message();
message.messagevalue();
```

Comment: So the main difference between a field and a variable, is that in the field you can manipulate the methods and values from the type of the field? (which would be a class) (thank you a lot btw)

Comment: @LucasMella Not exactly. Firstly, fields and variables aren't opposites, as the MS docs says, a field is a variable, just in a different position. What makes a variable a field is if it's declared in the main body of class. If it's declared in a function, it's just a variable. You can't access that variable from outside the function, not even in the same class, whereas, if it's a public field, it can be. I'm not sure what you mean by "*in* the field". All a field is is an address of memory. Variables can manipulate the methods and values of the type it belongs to as well.

Comment: And they both don't have to be in a class, it can be a struct as well. The main difference is where they're written and where they can be accessed.